# Update value in array list and apply it to all same value of the selected data php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So i will show my sample of table so that it easier to visualize the situation. This is program table.

```
ProgID  |   ProgramName |   SendNotifyToEmail
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.      |   A           | a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com, d@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.      |   B           | a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3.      |   C           | a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4.      |   D           | e@gmail.com, f@gmail.com, g@gmail.com
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5.      |   E           | d@gmail.com, e@gmail.com, f@gmail.com
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6.      |   F           | b@gmail.com, e@gmail, f@gmail
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so i try to SELECT

```
SELECT * from program where SendNotifyToEmail like '%d@gmail.com%'
```

and wanted to apply an update to the related value.

how to apply an update to all d@gmail.com to j@gmail.com using explode for each.

```
$query ="SELECT * from program where SendNotifyToEmail like '%d@gmail.com%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($line=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    $listmail = explode(",", trim($line["SendNotifyToEmail"]).',');
    foreach($listmail as $email=>$i)
        {
        ////
        }
}
```

Comment: Normalize your design. You shouldn't store multiple values like that.

Comment: yes i know i need to create another table to store a single email which linked to the program table. But its possible to do it without creating another table?

Comment: Sure it's possible, you already have the loop, just create a new email list and replace your old email with the new values in the inner loop and append it to the new list. Where exactly do you need help with that? Btw `$email=>$i` should be `$i=>$email` or just ignore the key in your loop, since you only need the email. Btw2 The `mysql_*` interface is deprecated please use MySQLi or PDO instead. :)

Comment: im not changing the whole list. i need to change some of data in the list..

Comment: Well you have to build a new string (your email list is just a string after all), if you want to change some of the values, maybe a `preg_replace` or something might also work to replace your mails without your inner loop, but that is essentially the same.

Comment: It's really a simple (if rather blunt) choice. Either normalise the design, or don't bother using an RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an often done procedure or if your database is small enough you may do it with a single query.

```
UPDATE program SET SendNotifyToEmail = REPLACE(SendNotifyToEmail, 'd@gmail.com', 'j@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me is solution to change database structure. `SendNotifyToEmail` should contain id of email saved in separate table, or you can have table with `ProgramName`, table with emails and join table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two tables and
Link them together with a foreign key

first table :`ProgID  |   ProgramName |`

second table: `EmailId | Prog_ForignId | SendNotifyToEmail`